# How to get values of List<Marker> into of my own class stored in Database of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this class Itinerary:

```
/**
* Created by alejandro on 18-10-16.
*/

public class Itinerario {

private String nombre;
private String descripcion;
private List<Marker> puntos;
private String fecha;

public Itinerario(String usuario, List<Marker> puntos, String descripcion, String fecha) {

    this.nombre = usuario;
    this.puntos = puntos;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.nombre = usuario;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public List<Marker> getPuntos() {
    return puntos;
}

public void setPuntos(List<Marker> puntos) {
    this.puntos = puntos;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}
}
```

And I save the Objects on Database with this Method:

```
Itinerario prueba = new Itinerario("Prueba",
                        markers,
                        "desc",
                        String.valueOf(fecha.getTime()));
                myRef.child("myitineraries").child(String.valueOf(fecha.getTime())).setValue(prueba);
```

I Get all values of Firebase Database with this and I put one by one in a List

```
//Declare
public ArrayList<Itinerario> resultsItinerarios = new ArrayList<>();


myRefItinerary.child("myitineraries").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Itinerario obj = null;

            try {

                List<Marker> map = (List<Marker>) dataSnapshot.child("puntos").getValue();

                obj = new Itinerario(
                        dataSnapshot.child("usuario").getValue().toString(),
                        map,
                        dataSnapshot.child("descripcion").getValue().toString(),
                        dataSnapshot.child("fecha").getValue().toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if (obj != null) {
                //List<Marker>
                resultsItinerarios.add(obj);

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Itinerario obj = null;

            try {

                List<Marker> map = (List<Marker>) dataSnapshot.child("puntos").getValue();

                obj = new Itinerario(
                        dataSnapshot.child("usuario").getValue().toString(),
                        map,
                        dataSnapshot.child("descripcion").getValue().toString(),
                        dataSnapshot.child("fecha").getValue().toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if (obj != null) {
                resultsItinerarios.remove(obj);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But always i need to retrieve the values of Markers inside my List resultsItinerarios,

Example:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A: " 
+ getResultsItinerarios().get(0).getPuntos().get(0).getPosition().latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I Get this Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
```

But if I use this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A: " 
+ getResultsItinerarios().get(0).getPuntos().get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

(Without getPosition().latitude or getPosition().longitude) I get all values presents even latitude and longitude.

This is the output:

```
10-19 03:10:52.203 29076-29076/cl.datacomputer.alejandrob.gogps I/ExampleGOGps: 

{draggable=false, alpha=1, infoWindowShown=false, id=m0, rotation=208877154, visible=true, zindex=0, position={latitude=-33.5174604, longitude=-70.7830533}, flat=false}
```

And I couldn't find a way to get the data, I attach a image of Firebase Database.

[image: 1]

Please i need your help.

Kind Regards.

Alejandro B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Custom Objects are stored in Firebase as Maps/HashMaps. So if you need to access the object;

Either Access it like any other map

or allow firebase (jackson - last time I checked) to use reflection

```
Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = dataSnapshot.child("puntos").getChildren().iterator();
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      DataSnapshot next = iterator.next();
      String key = next.getKey();
      Marker marker = next.getValue(Marker.class);

      markers.add(marker);
}
//Do this for the others and create you Itenerario Object
```

Comment: Thanks you, excellent the problem has been solved in minutes.
You are the best!!!!! :D
Regards.

Comment: *firebaser here* On the 9.x versions Jackson is not built-in anymore, but there is a custom serializer/deserializer. If needed you can still *use* Jackson, you just have to add the dependency yourself.